# Extract conditional modes from multilevel logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4, multilevel-analysis

I am estimating a multilevel logistic regression predicting the likelihood of making an error on a given trial. The model has random effects of participant, scenario, and actor, as well as fixed effects based on two variables and their interaction. The results are below:

```
a1 <- glmer(errorDummy ~ race*object + #fixed effects
  (1|participant) + (1|scenario) + (1|actor), #random effects
  data = df, 
  control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"),
  family = binomial(link = "logit")) #binomial 
print(summary(a1), correlation = F) #decision to shoot

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: errorDummy ~ race * object + (1 | participant) + (1 | scenario) + (1 | actor)
   Data: df
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  6704.4   6759.2  -3345.2   6690.4    18397 

Scaled residuals: 
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-2.557 -0.230 -0.108 -0.045 40.303 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 participant (Intercept) 0.6115   0.7820  
 actor       (Intercept) 0.8919   0.9444  
 scenario    (Intercept) 1.3102   1.1446  
Number of obs: 18404, groups:  participant, 630; actor, 20; scenario, 8

Fixed effects:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          -4.1705     0.4666  -8.938   <2e-16 ***
raceblack             0.1942     0.4410   0.440     0.66    
objectgun            -2.9482     0.1059 -27.846   <2e-16 ***
raceblack:objectgun  -0.3143     0.2074  -1.516     0.13    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The model shows that errors are uncommon in this task. However, they do vary across scenario:

```
coef(a1)$scenario
              (Intercept) raceblack objectgun raceblack:objectgun
alley           -2.331117 0.1942088 -2.948222          -0.3142849
domesticphone   -3.539802 0.1942088 -2.948222          -0.3142849
grocery         -5.314944 0.1942088 -2.948222          -0.3142849
parkinglot      -4.098250 0.1942088 -2.948222          -0.3142849
pulloverday     -3.084138 0.1942088 -2.948222          -0.3142849
pullovernight   -3.971451 0.1942088 -2.948222          -0.3142849
sidewalk        -5.619601 0.1942088 -2.948222          -0.3142849
warehouse       -4.539444 0.1942088 -2.948222          -0.3142849
```

What I want is an estimate of the conditional modes (Best Linear Unbiased Prediction?) for each of the eight scenarios  **on the proportion scale**. That is, I want an estimate of the likelihood of making an error on a trial for a given scenario.

I know that the formula to do this for, say, the intercept, in a non-multilevel logistic regression would be p = exp(logit) / (1 + exp(logit). Which would translate into p = exp(-4.1705) / (1 + exp(-4.1705)). But I am sure this is problematic in a multilevel context with random factors.

What is the appropriate way to estimate the likelihood of making an error on a trial in a given scenario? And are there packages available in R that might have this functionality built in?

Comment: As far as I know, the `predict` method for `glmer` models should do this, it will include the conditional modes for the random effect levels in the data you're predicting from by default (controlled by the `re.form` argument). See https://gist.github.com/tmalsburg/df66e6c2ab494fad83ee